# How to count for each type of label in column and save them in a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have to count for number of time 1's and 0's appear in a column of a data frame. I have tried the following code:

```
count_own_party = len(df['Deviation from Partisanship']== 1)
count_opposing_party = len(df['Deviation from Partisanship'] == 0)

print(count_own_party)
print(count_opposing_party)
```

It gives the same output of : 7854 for both the values. While it can be seen clearly from the [image: graph] that number of 1's are greater than number of 0's.

Comment: df['Deviation from Partisanship']== 1 returns bool array of the same length. `len(df[df['Deviation from Partisanship']== 1])`

Comment: `df['Deviation from Partisanship' ] == 1)` returns a boolean array of ones and zeros and it will have the same length as the series itself. Try `df['Deviation from Partisanship' ] == 1).sum()` instead.

Comment: for this there is a function in pandas, this is `Series.valu_counts`

Comment: How does the dataframe look, do you have a count for each persons deviation as 1 or 0, or is it a total, a small sample of the data would help if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this there is a function in pandas:
 [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
value_count=df['Deviation from Partisanship'].value_counts()
count_0=value_count[0]
#count_0=value_count['0'] # if it is str
count_1=value_count[1]
#count_1=value_count['1'] # if it is str
```

---

Here is an example:

```
print(df)
    Mnth  Income
0    Jan      80
1    Feb      80
2    Mar      50
3  April      60
4    May      60
```

---

```
value_count=df['Income'].value_counts()
print(value_count)



60    2
80    2
50    1
Name: Income, dtype: int64
```

---

```
count_60 = value_count[60]
print(count_60)
#2
```